# How do I allow sentences to begin with lowercase letters?

Tags: spell-checking

My spellchecker wants me to begin every sentence with a capital letter, i.e., it underlines lowercase characters after full stop. Can I make it stop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's the [`'spellcapcheck'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27spellcapcheck%27) option; from the help:

> Pattern to locate the end of a sentence.  The following word will be checked to start with a capital letter.  If not then it is highlighted with SpellCap `hl-SpellCap` (unless the word is also badly spelled).

The default value is `[.?!]\_[\])'" \t]\+`, but it may be set when loading a spell file (to accommodate the language's specific rules).

If you want to disable it, you should therefore use `:set spellcapcheck=` *after* using `:set spell` and `:set spelllang`. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an autocmd to help you here, but you can use a mapping, e.g.:

```
nnoremap <Leader>ss :set spell!<CR>:set spellcapcheck=<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>sn :set spelllang=nl<CR>:set spellcapcheck=<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>se :set spelllang=en_gb<CR>:set spellcapcheck=<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>su :set spelllang=en_us<CR>:set spellcapcheck=<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>sd :set spelllang=de_de<CR>:set spellcapcheck=<CR>
```